# Error when running belvu Mojave: 10.14.3 (18D109)

Tags: macos, alignment, bioinformatics

I installed SeqTools as specified for MacOSx [here](https://www.sanger.ac.uk/science/tools/seqtools). However, when I was going to run belvu the following error come up:

```
-> belvu <*hmmalign.fasta>

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myuser/local/bin/belvu
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I installed the prerequisites for SeqTools using Conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gtk2
conda install -c anaconda pkgconfig
```

What am I missing here? What do you recommend to do to bypass the error?

Answer (score 1):

In the configuration step you need to specify that the libraries of GTK+ are found in your conda environment.

1.- Start a fresh intallation (delete current seqtools dir and start again).

2.- `./configure LDFLAGS="-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /path/to/conda/envs/myenv/lib/"`

3.- `make install`

seqtools (belvu, dotter, etc.) should work then